# Magento 2. How to write something custom in Redis?

Tags: magento2, redis

My question is quite simple. I want to write something in redis, a value, a string, anything.

Is there any object available, some interface, that I can easily inject and store something there?

Looking for something like this:

```
$this->storageRedis->store($key, $value);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inbuilt `Credis` from magento.

For example:

```
require 'Credis/Client.php';
$redis = new Credis_Client('tls://127.0.0.1:6379');
//Set some value with key awesome    
$redis->set('awesome', 'absolutely');
//Get value with key awesome
echo sprintf('Is Credis awesome? %s.\n', $redis->get('awesome'));
```

**Note:** Above is direct code example you can try. You need to create Interface and implementation model class.

For more detail you can refer below readme:

> vendor/colinmollenhour/credis/README.markdown